# How to subset automatically in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS, so this might be a silly type of question.
Assume there are several datasets with similar structure but different column names. I want to get new datasets with the same number of rows but only a subset of columns. 
In the following example, `Data_A` and `Data_B` are original datasets and `SubA` and `SubB`are what I want. What is the efficient way of deriving `SubA` and `SubB`?

```
DATA A_auto;
  LENGTH A_make $ 20;
  INPUT A_make $ 1-17 A_price A_mpg A_rep78 A_hdroom A_trunk A_weight A_length A_turn A_displ A_gratio A_foreign;
CARDS;
AMC Concord        4099 22 3 2.5 11 2930 186 40 121 3.58 0
AMC Pacer          4749 17 3 3.0 11 3350 173 40 258 2.53 0
Audi Fox           6295 23 3 2.5 11 2070 174 36  97 3.70 1
;
RUN;

DATA B_auto;
  LENGTH make $ 20;
  INPUT B_make $ 1-17 B_price B_mpg B_rep78 B_hdroom B_trunk B_weight B_length B_turn B_displ B_gratio B_foreign;
CARDS;
Toyota Celica      5899 18 5 2.5 14 2410 174 36 134 3.06 1
Toyota Corolla     3748 31 5 3.0  9 2200 165 35  97 3.21 1
VW Scirocco        6850 25 4 2.0 16 1990 156 36  97 3.78 1
;
RUN;

 DATA SubA; 
   set A_auto;
   keep A_make A_price;
RUN; 


 DATA SubB; 
   set B_auto;
   keep B_make B_price;
RUN;
```

Comment: Just a note that SAS has naming/list short cuts for prefixes but not for suffixes. So if you have any control over the variable naming it's better to use a naming convention such as Price_A, Price_B instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my new answer.  This introduces quite a few concepts, but all are necessary to complete this task.

First of all I would store the required part variable names (the suffixes that are common to all datasets) in a new dataset.  This keeps them all in one place and makes it easier to change if required.

The next step is to create a regular expression (regex) search string that combines all the names, separated by a pipe (|), which is the regex symbol for `or`.  I've also added a $ symbol to end of the names, this ensures only variables ending with the part names will be selected.
`select into :[macroname]` is the method to create macro variables within `proc sql`

Then I set up a macro to extract the specific variable names for the current dataset and use those names to create a view (like my original answer)
The `dictionary` library referenced in the `proc sql` is a metadata library that contains information on all active libraries, tables, columns etc, so is a good source of identifying what the actual variable names are called (based on the regex search string created earlier).

You won't need the `proc print` in your code, I just put it in to show everything is working as expected.

Let me know if this works for you

```
/* create intial datasets */
DATA A_auto;
  LENGTH A_make $ 20;
  INPUT A_make $ 1-17 A_price A_mpg A_rep78 A_hdroom A_trunk A_weight A_length A_turn A_displ A_gratio A_foreign;
CARDS;
AMC Concord        4099 22 3 2.5 11 2930 186 40 121 3.58 0
AMC Pacer          4749 17 3 3.0 11 3350 173 40 258 2.53 0
Audi Fox           6295 23 3 2.5 11 2070 174 36  97 3.70 1
;
RUN;

DATA B_auto;
  LENGTH B_make $ 20;
  INPUT B_make $ 1-17 B_price B_mpg B_rep78 B_hdroom B_trunk B_weight B_length B_turn B_displ B_gratio B_foreign;
CARDS;
Toyota Celica      5899 18 5 2.5 14 2410 174 36 134 3.06 1
Toyota Corolla     3748 31 5 3.0  9 2200 165 35  97 3.21 1
VW Scirocco        6850 25 4 2.0 16 1990 156 36  97 3.78 1
;
RUN;


/* create dataset containing partial name of variables to keep */
data keepvars;
input part_name $ :20.;
datalines;
_make
_price
;
run;


/* create regular expression search string from partial names */
proc sql noprint;
select 
    cats(part_name,'$') /* '$' matches end of string */
into 
    :name_str separated by '|' /* '|' is an 'or' search operator in regular expressions */
from 
    keepvars;
quit;

%put &name_str.; /* print search string to log */


/* macro to create views from datasets */
%macro create_views (dsname, vwname); /* inputs are dataset name being read in and view name being created */

/* extract specific variable names to be kept, based on search string */ 
proc sql noprint;
select 
    name 
into
    :vars separated by ' '
from 
    dictionary.columns
where   
        libname = 'WORK' 
    and memname = upper("&dsname.") 
    and prxmatch("/&name_str./",strip(name))>0; /* prxmatch is regular expression search function */
quit;

%put &vars.; /* print variables to keep to log */

/* create views */
data &vwname. / view=&vwname.;
set &dsname. (keep=&vars.);
run;

/* test view by printing */
proc print data=&vwname.;;
run;

%mend create_views;

/* run macro for each dataset */
%create_views(A_auto, SubA);
%create_views(B_auto, SubB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you still need to define the view for all of the existing datasets. I have 20 datasets and I need 50 columns in each dataset. It takes a long time defining all of the views and the variables one by one.

Comment: Ok, your question wasn't clear in that respect.  What I need to know is if the naming convention of all 50 columns is similar in each dataset (e.g. column 1 always ends with _make, as per your example).  if this is the case then I can give you a macro solution

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. I guess the answer to your question is yes. I mean the names are quite similar. They start with different letters (like A for the first one and B for the second) but all end with the same name(like _make in this case).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner in SAS so I can not grasp every part of your code. However I code manage to tweak it to work for my actual datasets.

Comment: Glad it worked, I appreciate there's a lot in there for a beginner!  It's worth taking a bit of time afterwards to read up on the various concepts used, no doubt you'll need them again in the future.  The metadata (dictionary) tables can been seen as views in the SASHELP library.  The table I used (`dictionary.columns`) is stored as `sashelp.vcolumn` the other main one I use is `sashelp.vtable` (or `dictionary.tables`)